# SQL insert a foreach select on same table?

Tags: sql, select, insert

Can I, instead of doing this via PHP, combine this in 1 sql statement?

```
object_ids = "select object_id from `wp_term_relationships` where `term_taxonomy_id` = 14;";
foreach(object_ids as object_id) 
{
    "insert into `wp_term_relationships` VALUES (" . object_id . ",1597,0);";
}
```

*(for WordPress: for every post that has a category (14) add a new term relationship (1597))*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `wp_term_relationships`
SELECT object_id, 1597, 0
FROM `wp_term_relationships`
WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` = 14;
```

Answer (score 1):

Better something like:

```
 INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships
 SELECT  object_id, 1597, 0
 FROM wp_term_relationships
 WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 14
```